# How to reduce size of my custom python type?

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, python-extensions

I created my own custom Python type. It stores an internal array of bytes. Even when there's no bytes in the array, the object takes up 32 bytes. How can I reduce that?

Here's how I defined my type:

```c
typedef struct {
    PyObject_VAR_HEAD
    uint8_t *data;
} BitStream;

static PyTypeObject BitStreamType = {
    PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL, 0)
    .tp_name = "my_module.BitStream",
    .tp_dealloc = (destructor) _BitStream_dealloc,
    .tp_basicsize = sizeof(BitStream),
    .tp_itemsize = sizeof(uint8_t),
    .tp_flags = Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT,
};
```

I exposed a method to create an instance of it with a certain number of bytes in the data array:

```c
static PyObject *
of_bytes(PyObject *self, PyObject *obj)
{
    unsigned long size = PyLong_AsUnsignedLong(obj);
    BitStream *bstream = (BitStream *) BitStreamType.tp_alloc(&BitStreamType, size);
    if (bstream == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    return (PyObject *) bstream;
}
```

I would *love*  for `of_bytes(0)` to have a size as close to 0 as possible, and `of_bytes(1)` to have a size close to 1, etc.

Unfortunately:

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(0)
24
>>> sys.getsizeof(of_bytes(0))
32
```

Why is it larger than `int`?

How can I reduce its size?

It only becomes consistently smaller than int when both objects have to represent numbers with more than 937 bits:

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(2 ** 937)
152
>>> sys.getsizeof(of_bytes(math.ceil(937 / 8)))
150
```

For any more bytes/bits than this, int never becomes smaller than it again.

But I want it to be smaller than, or at least the same size as, int for any number of bits stored.

Alternatively, since all I need is the byte array `uint8_t *data`, is there another way I can return such an array to my code without a 32-byte PyObject wrapper?

Comment: You do understand the purpose of the wrapper and how python objects generally work, right? If you don't want general purpose objects, use plain C.

Comment: Integer has a different memory layout than your class: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/63298930fb531ba2bb4f23bc3b915dbf1e17e9e1/Include/longintrepr.h#L85-L88, digits are allocated only when they needed: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/145bf269df3530176f6ebeab1324890ef7070bf8/Objects/longobject.c#L121-L142, For 0 no digits are needed thus only `sizeof(PyVarObject)`=24 are needed.

Comment: @MadPhysicist can I return plain C to python? (I don't understand the purpose of the wrapper)

Comment: If your data has always the same length you could do without `ob_size` (-8byte), otherwise 32byte are what you need.

Comment: @ead that struct `_longobject` looks to same to me as my `BitStream`

Comment: @ead is `int` smaller because it doesn't store `ob_size` ? How can it do that despite having `PyObject_VAR_HEAD`

Comment: @minseong: 1) uint32_t* and uint32_t[1] are not quite the same, so no your definition is different 2) The logic is in _PyLong_New -> it doesn't not store digits, if there are 0 of them (but obviously stores `ob_size` thus 24 bytes needed).

Comment: @ead it is smaller all the way up to 118 bytes, how does it manage to do that?

Comment: @minseong example for one digit: `sizeof(unint32_t[1])=4`, but `sizeof(uint32_t*)+1*uint32_t=1`. Python uses only 30bits (and not 32bits) of a digit, so for bigger numbers you can catch up.

Comment: @ead would you like to post an answer? I still can't understand. For example, how is it possible for `digit ob_digit[1]` to be resized...

Comment: @ead PyLong_Type doesn't have a tp_dealloc destructor... how are PyLongObjects tidied up?

Comment: one needs `free` for `uint32_t*` but not `uint32_t[1]`, so there is nothing to tidy. The memory for `ob_digit` is allocated together with `PyVarObject` (https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/145bf269df3530176f6ebeab1324890ef7070bf8/Objects/longobject.c#L134) and will de deallocated together with it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Now I achieve sizes of 24 bytes + however many bytes are in `data`.

Have to use `uint8_t data[1]` intstead of `uint8_t *data`.

Then need to allocate memory with `PyObject_InitVar`.

```c
typedef struct {
    PyObject_VAR_HEAD
    uint8_t data[1];
} BitStream;

static PyTypeObject BitStreamType = {
    PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL, 0)
    .tp_name = "my_module.BitStream",
    .tp_dealloc = 0,
    .tp_free = PyObject_Del,
    .tp_basicsize = offsetof(BitStream, data),
    .tp_itemsize = sizeof(uint8_t),
    .tp_flags = Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT,
};

static BitStream *
_BitStream_New(size_t size)
{
    BitStream *bstream = (BitStream *) PyObject_Malloc(offsetof(BitStream, data) + size);
    if (!bstream) {
        PyErr_NoMemory();
        return NULL;
    }
    PyObject_InitVar((PyVarObject*)bstream, &BitStreamType, size);
    return bstream;
}
```

It's been working so far.